# Change user selected Answer buttons class depending on if isCorrect is true or false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, classname, template-literals

I'm pretty new to React so aware my code is probably a bit of a mess and more complicated than it needs to be.

Currently when a user clicks an answer button "setDisabled" will disable that row of 4 buttons so the user can only select one answer button per question. The state "setButton" changes the button class to "buttonClicked" which changes the background colour to light grey (so the user can see which button they have clicked.

The score increments by 1 for each correct answer and the button "Check Answers" reveals the score.

What I am trying to do is: When the "Check Answers" button is clicked I want the buttons which the user has selected and are correct (they have isCorrect: true) to have their background colour turn green and the buttons which have been clicked by the user but are incorrect (isCorrect: false) to have their background colour turn red.

I have tried to experiment with template literals in the button className and trying some if else logic in the resultsClick function but i feel like I am tangling myself up a little in my head and potentially overcomplicating things.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

````
 function Quiz(props) {

  const questions = [
    {
      questionText: 'What is the Capital of France?',
      answerOptions: [
        { id: 0, answerText: 'London', isCorrect: false, answer: 0 },
        { id: 0, answerText: 'Paris', isCorrect: true, answer: 1 },
        { id: 0, answerText: 'Nice', isCorrect: false, answer: 2 },
        { id: 0, answerText: 'Lyon', isCorrect: false, answer: 3 },
      ],

    },
    {
       questionText: 'What is the Capital of the UK?',
       answerOptions: [
         { id: 1, answerText: 'London', isCorrect: true, answer: 4 },
         { id: 1, answerText: 'New York', isCorrect: false, answer: 5 },
         { id: 1, answerText: 'Sydney', isCorrect: false, answer: 6 },
         { id: 1, answerText: 'Bath', isCorrect: false, answer: 7 },
       ],

     },
     {
      questionText: 'Who turns out to be the true victor in the Battle of Armageddon in Mortal Kombat?',
      answerOptions: [
        { id: 2, answerText: 'Liu Kang', isCorrect: false, answer: 8 },
        { id: 2, answerText: 'Shang Tsung', isCorrect: false, answer: 9 },
        { id: 2, answerText: 'Raiden', isCorrect: false, answer: 10 },
        { id: 2, answerText: 'Shao Kahn', isCorrect: true, answer: 11 },
      ],

    },
    {
      questionText: 'Under what pseudonym did Stephen King publish five novels between 1977 and 1984?',
      answerOptions: [
        { id: 3, answerText: 'Richard Bachman', isCorrect: true, answer: 12 },
        { id: 3, answerText: 'J. D. Robb', isCorrect: false, answer: 13 },
        { id: 3, answerText: 'Mark Twain', isCorrect: false, answer: 14 },
        { id: 3, answerText: 'Lewis Carroll', isCorrect: false, answer: 15 },
      ],

    },
  ];

  const [startQuiz, setStartQuiz] = useState(true);

  function startClick() {
  setStartQuiz(current => !current);
   }

  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);

   const optionClicked = (optionId, isCorrect, answer) => {
     const newDisabledArray = [...disabled, optionId];
     setDisabled(newDisabledArray)
     const newClickedArray = [...button, answer];
     setButton(newClickedArray);
       if (isCorrect) {
        setScore(score + 1);
     }
     }



const [button, setButton] = useState([]);

const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState([]);

const [showResults, setShowResults] = useState(true);

function resultsClick() {
  setShowResults(current => !current);
 }


 function restartQuiz() {
  setStartQuiz(current => !current);
  setShowResults(current => true);
  setScore(0);
  setDisabled(current => []);
  setButton(current => []);
 }


  return(
    <div>
    {startQuiz ? 
      <div className="start-screen">
      <div className="start-text">
        <h1>Quizzical</h1>
          <p>Test your knowledge!</p>
          <button onClick={startClick}>Start Quiz</button>
       </div>
       
     </div> 
     
     : 


     <div className="quiz">
     
      
       <div className="firstQuestion">
          <h2>{questions[0].questionText}</h2>
          </div>
            <div className="firstAnswers">
            {questions[0].answerOptions.map((answerOption) => {
              const {id, isCorrect, answer, answerOptions} = answerOption
            return (
              <button
                
                className={button.includes(answer) ? "buttonClicked" : "button"}
              
              
              
                key={id}
                
                disabled={disabled.includes(id)}

                onClick={() => { 
                  optionClicked(id, isCorrect, answer);

                
                }}
               
                >
                {answerOption.answerText}
              </button>
                  );
                }
              )}
                  </div>


        <div className="secondQuestion">
          <h2>{questions[1].questionText}</h2>
          </div>
            <div className="secondAnswers">
              {questions[1].answerOptions.map((answerOption) => {
                const {id, isCorrect, answer, answerOptions} = answerOption
              return (
                <button 

                className={button.includes(answer) ? "buttonClicked" : "button"}

                key={id}
                
                disabled={disabled.includes(id)}

                onClick={() => { 
                  optionClicked(id, isCorrect, answer);
                
                }}>
                {answerOption.answerText}
              </button>
                  );
                }
              )}
                  </div>

        <div className="thirdQuestion">
          <h2>{questions[2].questionText}</h2>
          </div>
            <div className="thirdAnswers">
              {questions[2].answerOptions.map((answerOption) => {
                const {id, isCorrect, answer, answerOptions} = answerOption
                return (
                  <button 
                  
                    className={button.includes(answer) ? "buttonClicked" : "button"}
                   

                    key={id}
                    
                    disabled={disabled.includes(id)}
     
                    onClick={() => { 
                      optionClicked(id, isCorrect, answer);
                    
                    }}>
                    {answerOption.answerText}
                  </button>
                  );
                }
              )}
                  </div>

       <div className="fourthQuestion">
          <h2>{questions[3].questionText}</h2>
          </div>
            <div className="fourthAnswers">
              {questions[3].answerOptions.map((answerOption) => {
             const {id, isCorrect, answer, answerOptions} = answerOption
             return (
               <button 
                
                 className={button.includes(answer) ? "buttonClicked" : "button"}
               
               
               
                 key={id}
                 
                 disabled={disabled.includes(id)}
 
                 onClick={() => { 
                  optionClicked(id, isCorrect, answer);
                 
                 }}>
                 {answerOption.answerText}
               </button>
                  );
                }
              )}
                  </div>

      
<br></br>
      <div className="resultsSection">
         <button

           className="button"
         
           onClick={()=> resultsClick()}>
           Check Answers!
         </button>
         <h3 className="resultsText">{showResults ? <p>Score:</p> : <p>Score: {score}/4</p>}</h3>
         <button className="button" onClick={restartQuiz}>Restart Quiz</button>
     </div>


</div>

      
}
</div>

  )
  

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can set a style by checking `isCorrect` property withing `map` (at least I consider your're using). Consider this:

```js
answerOptions?.map((answer) => (
  <div style={{backgroundColor: answer.isCorrect ? 'Green' : 'Red'}}>{answer.answerText}</div>
))
```